# How to tell how small `h` is the in the finite difference?

Tags: numerical-methods, differential-equations, computation, numerical-computing

I'm doing a project required to compute the precise(up to a certain precession `N`) numerical derivatives of a function.
The usual approach was to use the finite difference types of algorithms, i.e.

```
(f(x+h)-f(x))/h
```

However, there's not many document to mention how small the `h` should be, or how to check the convergence or the stability of the results, as `h=0` had a different meaning in the numerical computation than symbolic computation.

How to tell how small `h` is in the finite difference for the precession `N`? Also, is there any numerical differentiation method that's stable under recurrent application, since the aim was to apply the differentiation up to 1000 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IEEE754 double precision the optimal value of h depends on f(x) and the value of f''(x), the second derivative of f at x. If you have an upper bound `M` of its absolute value, then the optimal h is (Scilab code below)

```
h_opt = 2*sqrt(%eps*f(x)/M)
```

For example, if f(x)=cos(x) and try to approximate f'(1), you have M=1 and

```
--> h_opt = 2*sqrt(%eps*cos(1))

h_opt =

   2.191D-08
```

If you try values of h between 10^-1 and 10^-16 and compute the difference between the forward approximation and the true value -sin(1)

```
format e
h=10.^-(1:16)';
[h -sin(1)-(cos(1+h)-cos(1))./h]

ans =

   1.000D-01   2.559D-02
   1.000D-02   2.687D-03
   1.000D-03   2.700D-04
   1.000D-04   2.701D-05
   1.000D-05   2.702D-06
   1.000D-06   2.701D-07
   1.000D-07   2.806D-08
   1.000D-08  -3.025D-09
   1.000D-09   1.302D-07
   1.000D-10   3.522D-07
   1.000D-11   3.522D-07
   1.000D-12   7.807D-05
   1.000D-13  -1.032D-03
   1.000D-14   2.299D-03
   1.000D-15   4.671D-02
   1.000D-16  -8.415D-01
```

you can see that the best precision is attained for h=10^-8, which is well predicted by the magnitude of h_opt. This video https://youtu.be/yeFJWtSnV7Y?t=2013 (in french) explains the computation of the optimal h.

Comment: But how to estimate the lowest upper bound of `f''(x)` if `f('x)` was not known? Because for h smaller than 1e-8 where M to the function was not known and set to a large value, it's clearly not accurate.

Comment: There is no alternative, unless you can use a complex step (see https://nhigham.com/2020/10/06/what-is-the-complex-step-approximation/)

Comment: Is there any paper with the Cauchy's integral formula? Does the integration better control the rounding error better than the finite differences?

Comment: Using complex Cauchy integrals allow to compute derivatives of order > 1, but for first derivative the complex step finite difference gives exact (up to machine precision) results.See https://www.hedonisticlearning.com/posts/complex-step-differentiation.html